# Redis Indexes: Storing full key vs. ID

Tags: redis

Given this example:

```
user:1 email bob@bob.com
user:1 name bob
```

Based on my research, all the examples create an "index" similar to the following:

```
user:bob@bob.com 1
```

My question is: wouldn't it be better to store it as "user:1"?  That would eliminate the need to concatenate the string in code.  Is there some other reason not to store the whole string?  Memory maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was specifically about storing the full key in the index or just a numeric ID which is part of this key.

Redis has a number of [memory optimizations](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) that you may want to leverage to decrease general memory consumption. One of these optimizations is the intset (an efficient structure to represent sets of integers).

Very often, sets are used as index entries, and in that case, it is much better to store a numeric ID rather than an alphanumeric key, to benefit from the intset optimization.

Your example is slightly different because a given email address should be associated to only one user. A unique hash object is fine to store the whole index. I would still use numeric ID here since it is more compact, and may benefit from future Redis optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've conveyed so far, I'd use Redis hashes. For example, I'd denormalize the data a bit and store is as `hmset users:1 email bob@bob.com name Bob` and 'hset users:lookup:email bob@bob.com 1'.

This way, I can retrieve the user using both his email ID or user ID. You could create more lookup hashes depending on your needs.

For more useful patterns, look at the [Little Redis book](http://openmymind.net/2012/1/23/The-Little-Redis-Book/), written by Salvatore Sanfilippo himself.

Comment: Actually, the author of The Little Redis Book is Karl Seguin. Salvatore contributed to the Italian translation though. I highly recommend it as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.